# Why does my app crash at start up when i add headerLayout in NavigationView?

Tags: android

I'm a self-taught soon to be Software Developer I'm still learning. I'm trying to make a navigation drawer. My problem is my app keeps crashing at startup when I add a headerLayout in the NavigationView Ex: app:headerLayout"@layout/headerLayout". When I remove the headerLayout the app works perfectly fine. But the app looks fine on the Android studio preview emulator, but when I run the app in genymotion it crashes at startup. I've even tried to run the app at a different API level in genymotion and it still crashes. Thank You for your assistant.

```
Manifest File:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.android.drawer">

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>

        </manifest>





  build.gradle(Module: app)



     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 26
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.example.android.drawer"
                minSdkVersion 23
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
        }

activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.drawer.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/darkgray"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/darkgray"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

MainActivity.class



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }}


drawermenu.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item
            android:title="Dashboard"
            android:id="@+id/dashboard"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24px"/>

        <item
            android:title="Event"
            android:id="@+id/event"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_event_black_24px"/>

        <item
            android:title="Search"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24px"/>

        <item
            android:title="Settings"
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24px"/>

        <item
            android:title="activities"
            android:id="@+id/Activities"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24px"/>

        <item
            android:title="Logout"
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24px"/>

    </menu>

header.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fractal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/hell"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/myName"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/yourEmail"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

StackTrace of crash:

    01-22 17:57:31.293 1706-1706/com.example.android.drawer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.android.drawer, PID: 1706
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.drawer/com.example.android.drawer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                  at com.example.android.drawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    01-22 17:57:31.297 1706-1706/com.example.android.drawer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:267)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:176)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:98)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                  at com.example.android.drawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 432000012 byte allocation with 6111604 free bytes and 87MB until OOM
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4174)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:207)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
                                                                                    ... 38 more
```

Comment: can you give the stacktrace of the crash ?

Comment: format your code properly

Comment: @ Anton Kazakov I formatted the code according to StackOverflow standard if it wasn't formatted they wouldn't let me submit the question. If you cant help Solve this problem move on.

Comment: @Ayusch I've added the stacktrace crash, it's the last. Thank you!

Comment: @Mykey this formatting is a little bit more difficult to work with. It’s best if you separate files into different blocks.

Comment: Anyway, your crash is due to `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 432000012 byte allocation with 6111604 free bytes and 87MB until OOM` so check if your `android:background="@drawable/fractal”` is too big or what’s going on. You’re trying to decode bitmaps that won’t fit in the existing available RAM.

Comment: I mean… a 432MB image is … INSANE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look further down the stack trace, you'll find this line:
`Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 432000012 byte allocation with 6111604 free bytes and 87MB until OOM`

I've never used GenyMotion, but their docs show this when looking for memory increase for the VM:
https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/03_Virtual_Devices/Managing_virtual_devices/Configuring_a_virtual_device.htm?Highlight=memory

Comment: There is absolutely no way to load, decode and display a 430 megabyte image in one pass like that. The problem has little to do with Genymotion and more to do with the fact that the OP is trying to do something that simply cannot be done that way. :)

Comment: True. My guess is one of these (or both) are massive: `@drawable/fractal` and `@drawable/hell`.

Comment: Well the names certainly suggest so. :)

Comment: @kunruh & Martin Marconcin, I Thank you both so much. I remove both of the images and the app didn't crash.